# Perl split pattern with delimiter at specific position

Tags: regex, perl

I have a strings which i wanted to split in perl with delimiter but at specific position.
$Str = d2a_orx_lego_clk
The output i wanted is d2a_orx , ie split only after second underscore.
The code i tried splits the string in two parts but at first underscore not at second.

```
#!/bin/perl

$str = d2a_orx_lego_clk;
#print join('_', split(/_/, $str )), "\n";
my ($k, $v) = split(/_/, $str, 2);
print "$k\n";
print "$v\n";
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Danish i would solve your problem with regex ;). And please write your string as following. my $str = "d2a_orx_lego_clk"; I would suggest to use the imports "use strict; use warnings;"

Comment: `split(/_[^_]+\K_/, $str, 2);`

Comment: Thanks Patrick and Сухой27 it works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my ($k, $v) = $str =~ /^([^_]*_[^_]*)_(.*)/;
```

Using a regex match works, and is much easier than getting split to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This code below works fine which splits the string with delimiter '_' and then join with same delimiter.

```
#!/bin/perl
$str = d2a_orx_lego_clk;
my @string = split(/_/, $str);
my $str= join '_',$string[0],$string[1];
print $str,"\n";
```